# Django: How Form or Field class render the widget? What's the process?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, widget

I have already implemented a class that extends `Widget` and i need to implement a validation system for this class but i believe that is not compatible with `Field` class because i have applied custom `render()` method and maybe this violating the [LSP principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (not sure). Here is an example:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils import formats
from django_future import format_html, flatatt

class InputGeneric(forms.Widget):
"""
Base class for all <input> widgets
"""
input_type = None # Subclasses must define this.
_to_str = None

def __init__(self, attrs=None, single_attrs=None):
    super(InputGeneric, self).__init__(attrs)
    self.single_attrs = single_attrs or ''

def get_attrs(self):
    return self.attrs

def get_attr(self, key):
    return self.attrs.get(key, None)

def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, single_attrs=None):
    '''
    *The default arguments of this function are:
    (self, name, value, attrs=None)
    - - - -
    single_attrs: is a string of HTML5 single attributes like "required", disabled"
    Example:
    render(single_attrs='required disabled')
    '''
    name = name or self.attrs.get('name', None)

    if name:
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type, name=name)
    else:
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, type=self.input_type)

    value = self.attrs.get('value', None)
    if value:
        # Only add the 'value' attribute if a value is non-empty.
        final_attrs['value'] = force_unicode(self._format_value(value))

    self._to_str = format_html('<input{0} {1} />', flatatt(final_attrs), single_attrs)
    return self._to_str

def get_rendered(self):
    return self.render(attrs=self.attrs, single_attrs=self.single_attrs)

def __str__(self):
    if self._to_str:
        return self._to_str
    self._to_str = self.render()
    return self._to_str

class InputText(InputGeneric):
input_type = 'text'

def __init__(self, attrs=None, single_attrs=None):
    if attrs.get('type', None) is not None:
        del attrs['type']
    super(InputText, self).__init__(attrs, single_attrs)
```

### django_future.py:

**Note:** The `six` library for Django1.3 is available here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/utils/six.py

```
'''
This Lib contains functions from future implemantations of Django (After v1.3).
'''
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils import encoding
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

    #The six lib is not included in Django 1.3
    #If you have 1.3 (as i have) you can search here in a future version of Django:
    #django.utils -> six
import six

def flatatt(attrs):
    """
    Convert a dictionary of attributes to a single string.
    The returned string will contain a leading space followed by key="value",
    XML-style pairs. It is assumed that the keys do not need to be XML-escaped.
    If the passed dictionary is empty, then return an empty string.

    The result is passed through 'mark_safe'.
    """
    return format_html_join('', ' {0}="{1}"', sorted(attrs.items()))

def format_html(format_string, *args, **kwargs):
    #django.utils.html
    """
    Similar to str.format, but passes all arguments through conditional_escape,
    and calls 'mark_safe' on the result. This function should be used instead
    of str.format or % interpolation to build up small HTML fragments.
    """
    args_safe = map(conditional_escape, args)
    kwargs_safe = dict([(k, conditional_escape(v)) for (k, v) in
                        six.iteritems(kwargs)])
    return mark_safe(format_string.format(*args_safe, **kwargs_safe))


def format_html_join(sep, format_string, args_generator):
    #django.utils.html
    """
    A wrapper of format_html, for the common case of a group of arguments that
    need to be formatted using the same format string, and then joined using
    'sep'. 'sep' is also passed through conditional_escape.

    'args_generator' should be an iterator that returns the sequence of 'args'
    that will be passed to format_html.

    Example:

    format_html_join('\n', "<li>{0} {1}</li>", ((u.first_name, u.last_name)
    for u in users))

    """
    return mark_safe(conditional_escape(sep).join(
            format_html(format_string, *tuple(args))
            for args in args_generator))


def is_protected_type(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, six.integer_types + (type(None), float, Decimal,
        datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time))

def force_text(s, encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='strict'):
    if isinstance(s, six.text_type):
        return s
    if strings_only and is_protected_type(s):
        return s
    try:
        if not isinstance(s, six.string_types):
            if hasattr(s, '__unicode__'):
                s = s.__unicode__()
            else:
                if six.PY3:
                    if isinstance(s, bytes):
                        s = six.text_type(s, encoding, errors)
                    else:
                        s = six.text_type(s)
                else:
                    s = six.text_type(bytes(s), encoding, errors)
        else:
            s = s.decode(encoding, errors)
    except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
        if not isinstance(s, Exception):
            raise encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args)
        else:
            s = ' '.join([force_text(arg, encoding, strings_only,
                    errors) for arg in s])
    return s
```

So, i would like to ask how exactly the `Field` class (or the `Form` class) takes the raw value (html) from the `Widget` and how applies the validation filters and returns the results. Please provide a small example with a description in order to understand the process.

***Note** that i already have seen the [Django code][3] and unfortunately i cannot understand completely the process.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all i have to say that my approach is not correct. It was wrong decision to remove `name` and `value` from `render()`'s arguments because indeed violates the *LSP principle*. Also the most fundamental things of an input field are `name` and `value` which are they included also in the *POST* request.

After that i discovered the process of the rendering inside [forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/forms/forms.py). The widget is rendered inside `BoundField()` class which calls automatically the `as_widget()` function when it's called. So [forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/forms/forms.py) do all the process of rendering.

*Next i demonstrate the process with a sample application.*

## App Structure

---

1) First we have our form class:

#### my_form.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(min_length = 2, max_length = 100, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'Type a subject...'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'span3', 'placeholder': 'Your email...'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': '5', 'placeholder': 'Type a message...'}))

    def clean_message(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['message']
        num_words = len(message.split())
        if num_words < 4:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Not enough words!")
            return message
```

2) Second our view:

#### views.py:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            try:
                send_mail(
                    cd['subject'],
                    cd['message'],
                    cd.get('email', 'noreply@anonymous.com'),
                    ['myemail@ahost.com'],
                )
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')

            return HttpResponseRedirect('thank-you/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    return render_to_response('/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

3) The template:

#### contact.html

```
{% if form.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">
        Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }} below.
    </p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact</legend>
        <div class="field">
            {{ form.subject.errors }}
        </div>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

## Processing Steps

---

1) User clicks the link who leads to our *views.py* `contact()` function which calls our form and serves it with our template.

2) Inside template when `{{ form.as_table }}` is called, the app goes inside [forms.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3/django/forms/forms.py) and finds `BaseForm()` class and then this function (copy-pasted):

```
def as_table(self):
    "Returns this form rendered as HTML <tr>s -- excluding the <table></table>."
    return self._html_output(
        normal_row = u'<tr%(html_class_attr)s><th>%(label)s</th><td>%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s</td></tr>',
        error_row = u'<tr><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>',
        row_ender = u'</td></tr>',
        help_text_html = u'<br /><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row = False)
```

3) The above function calls another function called `self._html_output(...)` and lives inside `BaseForm()` of course. This function is responsible for outputting the final result rendered by calling other smaller functions or classes.

### Some notes

---

- When `form = ContactForm()` is executed inside *views.py* then we know is called `ContactForm()` class. But this class is a subclass of `Form` which lives in *forms.py* and also `Form()` is a child of `BaseForm()` class. That means that `ContactForm()` inherits everything from `BaseForm()`.
- `Form()` class is empty. Only inherits from `BaseForm()` and it's used for inheritance purposes. The true parent of every form is `BaseForm()` class.
- At initialization time when `ContactForm()` and his parents `Form()` and `BaseForm()` are called some very important variables taking place, such as `self.fields` which contains all of the child's fields. In our example: `subject`, `email`, `message`.
  Other important variables are:

  - `self.data`: Contains the *POST* data
  - `self._errors`: Stores the errors after clean() has been called.

### Inside of `_html_output()`

---

This function iterates over `self.fields` (in our case over `subject`, `email`, `message`) and calls the class `BoundField()` for each one, like this:

`bf = BoundField(frm_clss, field, name)`

The first argument `frm_clss` is the `BaseForm()` class. The second is the current field in the list of fields (eg. `subject`) and the third is the actual name of the field given inside `ContactForm()`, so the three names are: "subject", "email" and "message".

At the end this function returns a "compiled" and marked safe string of all the widgets rendered.

```
output.append(normal_row % {
    'errors': force_unicode(bf_errors),
    'label': force_unicode(label),
    'field': unicode(bf),
    'help_text': help_text,
    'html_class_attr': html_class_attr
    })

    .
    .
    .

return mark_safe(u'\n'.join(output))
```

### BoundField() class

---

By default calls the `render()` method of a widget and returns the html string to the `BaseForm()` class (`_html_output()`).